# CKEditor charset

Tags: php, mysql, html, encoding, ckeditor

I updated my web app to use UTF-8 instead of ANSI.

I did the following measures to define charset:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8"); // PHP
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> // HTML
utf8_general_ci // In MySQL
```

I also edited the CKEditor config to remove htmlentities because I need the correct character (i.e. `é` and not `&eacute;`) for MySQL fulltext search.

```
config.entities = false;
config.entities_latin = false;
```

In the database (phpMyAdmin view) and on normal text fields output (HTML, `<input>` or `<textarea>`), everything looks fine (I see `é`, not `&eacute;`, not `Ã©`, yay).

However, CKEditor has some trouble with the encoding. See attached image for the same field taken from the database, displayed in a textarea, then in a textarea repalced by CKEditor:
[image: CKEditor Encoding Problems]

This seems to be in the CKEditor JavaScript code (probably a fixed charset), but I can't find it in the config. Again, since the `é` displays correctly in normal HTML (real UTF-8 `é`, not `&eacute;` nor `Ã©`), I'm quite sure it's not the PHP/MySQL query that's wrong (but I might be mistaken).

EDIT: This seems like a symptom of applying `htmlentities`, which by default is encoded in Latin-1, on UTF-8 text. There is either a possibility of using `htmlspecialchars` or to specify the charset ("utf-8"), but I don't know **where to modify that in CKEditor**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my approach that was wrong, not CKEditor's. Was looking in the wrong file and missed the UTF-8 encoding on a `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 8):

This thread seems bit dated but answering it to help anyone looking for a response.

To allow `CKEditor` to process the character `é` as `é` and not `&eacute`; set the config for `entities_latin` to `false`, as below:

```
config.entities_latin = false;
```

Or, you may just want to set following options to false:

```
config.entities = false;
config.basicEntities = false;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use in your database connection: `$connection->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`
And remember to set db, and/or table Collation to utf8... I prefer `utf8_general_ci`