# How to get kannada language from ckeditor

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

*From pdf file,i copied kannada words and paste it on the ckeditor,but it made some other fonts,how can i get proper kannada on the ckeditor and i want to insert it into database using codeigniter framework.please help me....My code for ckeditor integration is given below,*

**(Javascript code)**

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.8/standard/ckeditor.js"></script> 
<script>                           
    $(function () {
        $('#editor1').ckeditor({
            toolbar: 'Full',
            enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
            shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P
        });
    });
</script>
```

**(HTML code)**

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: Are you sure that ckeditor uses `UTF-8` encoding?

Comment: I thought CKeditor is UTF8 by default.how can i make sure ckeditor uses UTF-8

Comment: It might as well be default, but if it doesn't show the characters well it does seem to me like it is not. Maybe this question / answers can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653307/ckeditor-charset

Comment: Have you thought about all the parts in between you clients keyboard and the database? See: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) Since CKEditor is a JavaScript tool and thus uses UTF-16 internally. Usually the problem with mangled characters is the encoding of the web-page on which such an editor is used.

Answer (score 0):

so there are a language plugins available which you can use

ie:

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/language.

https://www.pramukhime.com/ckeditor-plugin

**Note:** If you don't have the fonts, the text will not display properly. Then you have to install that font first.